# Where do I ask questions related to coding, but not broken code or code review?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Actually, I want to know which Stack Exchange site can be used to ask questions that are related to coding, but not broken or not to check whether the code is efficient or not.

For example,

1. Is that a good idea to use jQuery in React
2. Which is good for beginners, npm or yarn?
3. Can React native control hardware devices?

These are a few questions that are very much off-topic on Stack Overflow or the code review site.

My actual questions are different, but somewhat similar to those.

Comment: The first 2 sound opinion based, and generally, opinion based questions aren't appropriate for most of the SE network. You may want to post on a discussion site instead.

Comment: Na my question are different I just want to ask which site is appropriate. For offtopic coding related questions.

Comment: @RaajNadar - There isn't a SE website for "offtopic coding" questions.  In the future, please ask if a question is appropriate, only if it is your real potential question

Answer (score 2):

I think the first two are *primarily opinion based*. You can make anything a bad idea. I suspect with *some* code, or at the very least very careful scoping, and an excellently written question with a realworld example, you could probably fit the last in SO.

The problem here isn't with code or lack of it though - its that many of these questions are, as per the help pages on most site

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This is the *real* issue with questions like this, and there's no real site that would handle questions like "is this a good idea" or "should I use A or B?"

Comment: No no my question are different. I want a place where I can ask the best lanuage that I can use to achieve a certain task in coding.

Comment: @RaajNadar "The best language" is entirely opinion based.

Comment: So this types of questions are against SE rules?

Comment: Quite literally https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask what this says. Its just not a good fit for a QA format that requires one correct answer.

Comment: @RaajNadar Generally, yes. SE sites are for objective questions, with the exception of a few sites like Interpersonal and Workplace that will always illicit some opinion.

Comment: Thanks for linking that page. I am clear what to ask and what not to ask now.